# Creating custom slider in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a custom slider using jQuery only I'm unsure on the best practice for how ot make this work.

My slider has 3 slides and a controls section each relating to a slide (1, 2, 3).

When a control is clicked I've got my slide fading out only I'm unsure on how to say if X control was clicked, add the active class to the relevant slide?

Ive made a fiddle to explain which i hope helps, what i need however is an explanation of the best practice in doing this?

Sorry if the questions hard to understand!

What I'm using to fade out my current slide, but then once its gone I cant rely on the active class to say add a class to the next element?

```
$('.ctrl-one').click(function(){
    $('.active .slide-img').animate({
        'marginRight' : "-=350px"
    }, 500, 'easeOutQuint', function(){
        $('.active .description').fadeOut().promise().done(function(){
            $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Esm97/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you need,try this code , but am sure you can find a lot different methods.

```
$('.controls a').click(function() {
                var current = $(this).attr('class').replace('ctrl-', '');

                if (!$('.sector-banner .' + current).hasClass('active')) {
                    $('.active').animate({
                        'marginRight': "-=350px"
                    }, 500, 'linear', function() {
                        $(this).fadeOut().promise().done(function() {
                            $(this).css('margin-right',0);
                            $(this).removeClass('active');
                            $('.sector-banner .' + current).addClass('active');
                            $('.sector-banner .' + current).fadeIn();
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Your code solved the issue by maintaining OP's version , a +1 for it